# I used jQuery to position the footer on the bottom of my page but there still some white space showing

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I used the following code to try and put the footer on the bottom of my web page but there is still some white space showing and I can't figure out what's causing it. When I right click and go to inspect, as soon as the developer tools open that white space disappears and its not showing any padding on the bottom of the footer.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).bind("load", function () {
        var footer = $("#footer");
        var pos = footer.position();
        var height = $(window).height();
        height = height - pos.top;
        height = height - footer.height();
        if (height > 0) {
            footer.css({
                'margin-top': height + 'px'
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Here is a link to my css file
[Codeshare Link](https://codeshare.io/ad3v6K)

Comment: Can you share your html code?

Comment: Instead of using jQuery, simply use css: `#footer { position;absolute;bottom:0; }`